# My esp32 is giving me the following error : rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x3 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2)) waiting for download

Tags: arduino, wifi, iot, esp32, nodemcu

I am using esp32 cam module. I have uploaded the code using arduino uno as UART programmer. The sketch was uploaded successfully but when I am pressing reset button of esp32 the following error comes up on serial monitor :
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x3 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2))
waiting for download
Please tell what exactly is the problem and what I should do to overcome it.

The code is not executing as expected

Answer (score 0):

The probelm you reported is about the boot button which is being pressed or is electrically short due to some reason, You have to debug the electric circuit yourself and look for any minor wire or any wire soldering issue. If you couldn't find the issue, then I would recommend to purchase new ESP32 dev Board, or ask any electrical niche to resolve the short issue in your board.